# Flag a message for follow-up without popping out in Outlook 2013

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2013

If you "pop out" a message in Outlook 2013, then there is an option to flag it for follow-up. Is there a way to do this without having to pop out the message? I'm allowed to customize the ribbon, so I assume that I can somehow add this option, but I can't find it anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

In the list of messages, hover over the one you want to follow-up on and a little flag will appear (above the date stamp).  Click it to flag for follow-up.

[image]

Comment: Yeah, this works for messages in my inbox but I want to do it while I'm sending a message. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: @Xodarap I'm not sure I follow? In my experience Office 2013 always uses a separate window for the editor when you're creating a new email. Are you talking about when Replying to an existing email? If so, then why not just click the "Home" tab while editing the reply, and then click the follow-up button?

Comment: Yes, I'm speaking about replying. I think if you click the "follow-up" button in the "home" tab, that will flag the message you have selected for follow-up, not the reply. Also it's inconvenient to have to switch tabs.

Comment: How i understand it, you want to flag the reply that you send, for followup. If this is the case, you can perform the steps mentioned in this answer, while you are on the 'sent items' folder as well. Let me know if this helps. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You right click on the message, then select Follow Up. There are pre-set times (Follow Up Today, This Week, Next Week, or Custom).

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but I want to do this while sending the message

Comment: You can set a rule to flag after you send it. An email you compose is not manipulatable until you save it or send it which saves it

Comment: If you have the popout compose window, then you can flag it. So I don't think it's true that you can't do this

Comment: Can you edit your post and post a screenshot of how pop out ribbon and non pop out differ?